# Is there a way to restrict the Android soft keyboard to allow ONLY emoji characters?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-input-method

I have an EditText that can ONLY be a SINGLE Emoji character. I've added code and a filter to ensure this, but I still have a usability problem because the keyboard pops up in NORMAL text mode. It's not obvious to the user that only an Emoji character is allowed.

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/activity_emoji"
    style="@style/Material.Widget.EditText.Light"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FF000000"
    android:text=""
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

Ideally I could disable all input except Emoji, but that appears to be impossible. Another option would be to have the keyboard pop up already on the Emoji page instead of on the normal alphabet. Is it possible to do that, and if so how?

Seems to me the simple solution would be supporting:

```
android:inputType="Emoji"
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've added code and a filter to ensure this

Since there is no requirement for an input method editor to offer emoji, you have a slight problem.

> I still have a usability problem because the keyboard pops up in NORMAL text mode

Many input method editors *only* have what you consider to be normal text mode.

Please understand that there are over 26,000 Android device models. These ship with dozens, if not hundreds, of pre-installed keyboards. Users can also install others from the Play Store, F-Droid, and elsewhere. None have to offer emoji. I would expect that relatively few do, though the ones that do (like GBoard) will be the most widely-used ones.

Also, please bear in mind that not all Android devices use soft keyboards. Sometimes, that's a fairly permanent state (e.g., Chromebooks). Sometimes, it is a temporary state (Bluetooth keyboard enabled, USB keyboard plugged in, other assistive device attached).

> Is it possible to do that, and if so how?

No, sorry.

Comment: Seems the easy solution would be a simple addition: android:inputType="Emoji".  Regardless, if I can only allow an emoji character in that field then how can I test to see if the device I'm on has emojis at all?  I could at least disable the field in that case.

Comment: @Bungles: "Seems the easy solution would be a simple addition: android:inputType="Emoji"." -- changing the implementation of all the world's soft keyboards seems like it would not qualify as "simple". "how can I test to see if the device I'm on has emojis at all?" -- ask the user. There is no way to ask the system if the current chosen input method editor supports emoji (or gestures or GIFs or pretty much anything). Alternatively, [build the emoji support into your app](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/33?sort=created).